# Permission Denial when trying to access contacts in Android

Tags: java, android, permissions, contacts

I am trying to access the contacts on the device and later display them in a list, however when I try to access them with a cursor, I get an error that I'm missing permissions for READ_CONTACTS but I have already gave permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml

Code where I access Contacts:

```
public void setupCursor() {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Toast.makeText(this, name + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="io.github.brady131313.textback" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityMainSettings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityContactSelect"
        android:label="Select Contacts">
    </activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

Error Log

```
05-17 17:12:41.544  20202-20202/io.github.brady131313.textback E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.github.brady131313.textback, PID: 20202
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.github.brady131313.textback/io.github.brady131313.textback.ActivityContactSelect}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{14c069a9 20202:io.github.brady131313.textback/u0a90} (pid=20202, uid=10090) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{14c069a9 20202:io.github.brady131313.textback/u0a90} (pid=20202, uid=10090) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2926)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1452)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:468)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:428)
            at io.github.brady131313.textback.ActivityContactSelect.setupCursor(ActivityContactSelect.java:46)
            at io.github.brady131313.textback.ActivityContactSelect.onCreate(ActivityContactSelect.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Case sensitivity is all important. Look at the error message and the case it's using... `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` then look at your manifest... `ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_CONTACTS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the uses-permission outside the application tag and make the android.permission lowercase. that should fix it as agreed below in comments

Comment: The OP is already declaring `<uses-permission />` outside of the `<application / >` element. The issue is with case-sensitivity - yes, it makes a difference.

Comment: Whoops, yeah I figured that was it if not outside the application tag :)

Answer (score 4):

Since the new [runtime permission model](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) is introduced in Android 6.0,

Hope this code will help if you want to use [runtime permission model](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions). You can also see detail implementation and get source code from [here](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/10/android-60-runtime-permission-model.html).

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // The ListView
    private ListView lstNames;

    // Request code for READ_CONTACTS. It can be any number > 0.
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the list view
        this.lstNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstNames);

        // Read and show the contacts
        showContacts();
    }

    /**
     * Show the contacts in the ListView.
     */
    private void showContacts() {
        // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        } else {
            // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
            List<String> contacts = getContactNames();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
            lstNames.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                showContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the name of all the contacts.
     *
     * @return a list of names.
     */
    private List<String> getContactNames() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Get the ContentResolver
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Iterate through the cursor
            do {
                // Get the contacts name
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contacts.add(name);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // Close the curosor
        cursor.close();

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: its showing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Answer (score 1):

i had same situation like what you have, basically you only need change "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" to lowercase for the first half you the permission.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>